# Header with forward declaration of MPI

Tags: c++, header, dependencies

I'm using a short MPI wrapper like this:

```
#ifndef INC_MyLib_MPIWRAPPER_H
#define INC_MyLib_MPIWRAPPER_H

#include <mpi.h>


/* libMyLib MPI struct & macros */
namespace libMyLib{
    extern int mpi_rank;
    extern int mpi_nranks;
    extern int mpi_msg;
    extern int mpi_msg_;
    extern MPI_Comm mpi_active_comm;
}

#define MPI_INIT MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); MPI_Comm_size( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_nranks ); MPI_Comm_rank( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_rank );
#define MPI_INIT_NULL MPI_Init(nullptr, nullptr); MPI_Comm_size( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_nranks ); MPI_Comm_rank( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_rank );
#define MPI_FINISH MPI_Finalize( );

#define MPI_INTERRUPT libMyLib::mpi_msg = 1; MPI_Allreduce(&libMyLib::mpi_msg, &libMyLib::mpi_msg_, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, libMyLib::mpi_active_comm);
#define MPI_ERROR_CHECK libMyLib::mpi_msg = 0; MPI_Allreduce(&libMyLib::mpi_msg, &libMyLib::mpi_msg_, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, libMyLib::mpi_active_comm);; if( libMyLib::mpi_msg_ > 0 ){throw std::runtime_error(" eror " );}

#endif //INC_MyLib_MPIWRAPPER_H
```

I'd like to get rid of `mpi.h` dependency here, so I tried to add a forward declaration of `MPI` types like this:

```
#ifndef INC_MyLib_MPIWRAPPER_H
#define INC_MyLib_MPIWRAPPER_H

#include <mpi.h>

/* MPI forward declarations to remove MPI header dependency from API */
typedef int MPI_Comm;
typedef int MPI_Datatype;
#define MPI_INT ((MPI_Datatype)0x4c000405)

typedef int MPI_Op;
#define MPI_SUM     (MPI_Op)(0x58000003)
int MPI_Allreduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, MPI_Comm comm);

#if defined(HAVE_VISIBILITY)
#define MPICH_API_PUBLIC __attribute__((visibility ("default")))
#else
#define MPICH_API_PUBLIC
#endif
int MPI_Finalize(void) MPICH_API_PUBLIC;
int MPI_Comm_size(MPI_Comm comm, int *size) MPICH_API_PUBLIC;
int MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_Comm comm, int *rank) MPICH_API_PUBLIC;
int MPI_Init(int *argc, char ***argv) MPICH_API_PUBLIC;

/* libMyLib MPI struct & macros */
namespace libMyLib{
    extern int mpi_rank;
    extern int mpi_nranks;
    extern int mpi_msg;
    extern int mpi_msg_;
    extern MPI_Comm mpi_active_comm;
}

#define MPI_INIT MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); MPI_Comm_size( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_nranks ); MPI_Comm_rank( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_rank );
#define MPI_INIT_NULL MPI_Init(nullptr, nullptr); MPI_Comm_size( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_nranks ); MPI_Comm_rank( libMyLib::mpi_active_comm, &libMyLib::mpi_rank );
#define MPI_FINISH MPI_Finalize( );

#define MPI_INTERRUPT libMyLib::mpi_msg = 1; MPI_Allreduce(&libMyLib::mpi_msg, &libMyLib::mpi_msg_, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, libMyLib::mpi_active_comm);
#define MPI_ERROR_CHECK libMyLib::mpi_msg = 0; MPI_Allreduce(&libMyLib::mpi_msg, &libMyLib::mpi_msg_, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, libMyLib::mpi_active_comm);; if( libMyLib::mpi_msg_ > 0 ){throw std::runtime_error(" eror " );}

#endif //INC_MyLib_MPIWRAPPER_H
```

The problem is, that in one code I need to combine this wrapper with the real `mpi.h` header and I'm getting errors like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/liblibMyLib.a(Reader.cpp.o): in function `libMyLib::Reader::read()':
Reader.cpp:(.text+0x10f3): undefined reference to `MPI_Allreduce(void const*, void*, int, int, int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: Reader.cpp:(.text+0x1764): undefined reference to `MPI_Allreduce(void const*, void*, int, int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**While I can understand, what's happening I'm curious if there's any way, how to make the forward declaration to be able to use the wrapper AND combine it with `mpi.h` header, if needed?**

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You are declaring the functions with C++ language linkage, but `mpi.h` declares them with C language linkage (which is the correct thing to do as the library is a C library).

Comment: @uneven_mark This "linkage inconsistency" is probably just because of my little experience with C++ - could you, please, explain it in a little more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to do this or whether it will work correctly at all, but the particular error you are observing right now is because MPI is a C library.

C++ treats C entities separately from C++ entities. So if you declare a function `MPI_Allreduce` in C++ code it does not refer to the same function `MPI_Allreduce` that you would have gotten if you used the same declaration in C code.

In order to make a name refer to the C entity, you have to declare it with C language linkage, which is done with

```
extern "C" {
    // declarations go here
}
```

You can look into `mpi.h` to see that it does the same thing.